# How to compare string with array of words and highlight words in string that match?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this issue, I have an array of words like this

```
let words = ['prueba', 'etiquetas'];
```

and my string

`let product = 'Prueba de etiquetas';`

This array of words and string will be different all time, every product contains its own array of words, and I would like to know which of these words are in the string and highlight these words in the string, in this case when I want to print the `product`variable the output should be:

**Prueba** de **etiquetas**

My code so far is this

```
if (words.length) {

    for (let x = 0; x < words.length; x++) {

        if (product.toUpperCase().indexOf(words[x].toUpperCase()) !== -1) {

            //Here I need to hightligh the words in the string
        }
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to make that change in the `product` variable, some ideas? Am I doing something wrong? I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: @hellcode HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the array to a regular expression, and use [String#Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to wrap the words with a span:

```js
const words = ['prueba', 'etiquetas'];
const product = 'Prueba Pruebaa de etiquetas aetiquetas';

// convert the array to a regular expression that looks for any word that is found in the list, regardless of case (i), over all the string (g)
const regexp = new RegExp(`\\b(${words.join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');

// replace the found words with a span that contains each word
const html = product.replace(regexp, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');

demo.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: you could omit the relacement function with just a standard replace: `const html = product.replace(regexp, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');`

Comment: You might want to wrap each word with the word boundary `\b` specifier before joining them together so that you don't accidentally detect parts of words that are unrelated: ``words.map(word => `\\b${word}\\b`).join('|')``

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - good idea, but you can also skip the map by using `\\b(${words.join('|')})\\b`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution without regex:

```js
let words = ['prueba', 'etiquetas'];
let product = 'Prueba de etiquetas';

words = words.map(function(word) { return word.toLowerCase(); });

product = product.split(' ').map(function(word) { 
             return words.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ? '<b>'+word+'</b>' : word; 
          }).join(' ')

console.log(product);
```

Comment: I like this answer but I solved first my problem with @OriDrori answer, thank you.

Comment: This answer is really useful and very simple to understand. Thanks @ivo

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```js
var words   = ["product", "words"],
    product = "This arrAy of wOrds aNd String wiLl be dIFferent all tiMe, evEry pRoduCt conTaiNs its own arRay oF words.";
    
var regex = new RegExp('(' + words.join('|') + ')', "ig");

document.body.innerHTML = product.replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, this answer works as well to solve my problem but I solved the problem with @OriDrori answer, +1.