# Wrap all occurences of Array<word> in string in <em></em> Javascript, allowing "em" to be a word

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

The usecase: I have a search input that allows users to enter space-separated words to search for in a list of entries. I want to only display matches that match any of the words provided, and highlight those parts of the entries that match.

Given this array of haystacks:

```
const haystacks = [
 { value: 'Hello World', visible: true }, 
 { value: 'I was here', visible: true }, 
 { value: 'tell me your name', visible: true }
];
```

and this array of needles

```
const needles = ['el', 'rl', 'em'];
```

how can I wrap all matching parts of the strings in `<em></em>`, and for those that have no match set `visible: false`:

```js
// expected result
[
  { value: 'H<em>el</em>lo Wo<em>rl</em>d', visible: true }, 
  { value: 'I was here', visible: false }, 
  { value: 't<em>el</em>l me your name', visible: true }
]
```

I have checked [How to compare string with array of words and highlight words in string that match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123744/how-to-compare-string-with-array-of-words-and-highlight-words-in-string-that-mat) but that one only highlights words that fully comply with the needles, not partial matches.

Here's what I've tried, which gives me

```js
[
  { value: "H<<em>em</em>>el</<em>em</em>>lo Wo<<em>em</em>>rl</<em>em</em>>d", visible: true },
  { value: "I was here", visible: false },
  { value: "t<<em>em</em>>el</<em>em</em>>l th<em>em</em> your name",    "visible": true }
]
```

```js
const haystacks = [{ value: 'Hello World', visible: true }, { value: 'I was here', visible: true }, { value: 'tell them your name', visible: true }];

const needles = ['el', 'rl', 'em'];

for (const haystack of haystacks) {
  for (const needle of needles) {
    const isMatchingOption = haystack.value.toLowerCase().includes(needle);
    haystack.visible = isMatchingOption;
    if (isMatchingOption) {
      const re = new RegExp(needle.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, '\\$1'), 'gi');
      haystack.value = haystack.value.replace(re, '<em>$&</em>');
    }
  }
}

console.log(haystacks);
```

Comment: `filter` and then `map`?

Comment: The code I have so far is from a far more complex use case and not working despite working on it for almost 2 hours. I'm stuck and thus I simplified the problem in hopes for someone seeing what I currently fail to see.

Comment: I have added a simplified version of my problematic approach.

Comment: So the initial values of `visible` are irrelevant?

Comment: @trincot : Correct.

Comment: Had also started to play with this. If you're still interested, [my idea is here (demo)](https://tio.run/##hZFLb8IwEITv/hVzqOpYTcO14tUTUnuq1EsPiIMJSxLixJHt8BDlt6cOIRSpSL3Y0u7seL71Rm6ljU1WueftS9PEurQOJdFKkcUEc06Kh@DmfFLBFyPGOlEqD9bJOD/LGI7YSlXTEPyNlNL40kat/NA2s9lS@bozNeEU4lb6jp20SMnQf0rnTVEQDro2KGVxZ4C12QYDJFSSkY7gUkIlnSNTYm100XMxs/eZS9rhk5LZvgp48DrkeOr70UZnZcC/ufA1LlryLOFi1Jq37FpRpHQSmL3oXjRUKRkTCunilGwIS65PB6exlsoS@1huKHZRTgcbXJcnokJWQZCHIIHJFEcGZGtvHTmy7lc3zxfReRdCnDXA35aH@luMLuG8ZcjHVEwfHscDf7U8wAnko911vMSfdOlHaNXsdCH2mHHefUZWVrVj19lorc1MxmlALc7tuqgL5El7cyFGaJof).

Comment: @bobblebubble Boils down to what Trincot has in his answer.

Comment: @connexo Trincot's answer is much more diligent (sorting needles descending by length, escaping, ...). Was just playing around with your task out of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should aim to create only one, comprehensive regular expression, not one per needle:

```js
const regEscape = s => s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\\]/g, "\\$&");

function highlight(haystacks, needles) {
    // Sort needles by descending length (in a copy)
    needles = [...needles].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
    const regex = RegExp(needles.map(regEscape).join("|"), "gi");
    return haystacks.map(({value}) => ({
       value: value.replace(regex, `<em>$&</em>`),
       visible: regex.test(value)
    }));
}

// Example run:
const haystacks = [
    { value: 'Hello World' }, 
    { value: 'I was here' }, 
    { value: 'tell me your name' }
];

const needles = ['el', 'rl', 'em'];

console.log(highlight(haystacks, needles));
```

The needles are sorted by descending length so that if one is a substring of the other, the longer one gets precedence for the replacement.

Comment: I was lacking the knowledge to properly merge the needles into a single regex. Thanks alot for your answer. What if the needles were `['el', 'lo']`?

Comment: You may need to influence the order of needles, as that will matter when one needle is a substring of another. In that case you need to sort the needles by descending length. In fact, I'll add that to my answer now.

Comment: `el` and `lo` have the same length, tho. When I think about it, I'm not even sure about what the result should look like.

Comment: ~~So what if a haystack has overlapping matches and I want only the first match to be wrapped in that case?~~ I see your code already does exactly that.

Comment: When needles are equal length, and they overlap, the one that comes first in the haystack will be matched (irrespective of their relative order in the needles). This is because a regex will traverse the haystack from left to right, and so when it hits a match, it will do the replacement, and then continue **after** that match.